# Find duplicate in excel column and show corresponding cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am attempting to use excel functions to find the value of the corresponding value of a cell of which has a duplicate within a column. That is, if value of B2 appears 2 times in column B, say B4, I am to find the value of A4. I have the following sample data for clarity:

A, B

123, 1.2.3.4

321, 2.2.2.2

111, 3.3.3.3

678, 1.2.3.4

As "1.2.3.4" appears twice, I will like to display value of A4 which is "678".

I have the following on hand, seems to be able to pick up duplicates but I got stuck on using VLOOKUP to pull the value of the corresponding cell.

```
IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B4)>1, VLOOKUP(B4,A:B,1),FALSE), "False")
```

I try only using the VLOOKUP function but it returns a "N/A" error.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple:

C1: `=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B1)>1,A1,"")`

C4: `=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B4,B4)>1,A4,"")`